# Lookup a value in a list, if not found use previous value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We have a list with rooms and guest living in the rooms.
We want to find the room number for each person.
The room number is only filled in for the first person in the room, because it is better for the layout.

**How can I find the room number in spite of there is no room number to the left of some people?**

My idea was to just take the latest number in the list from that row where the name was found.

I stack all 3 lists into one with a Vstack and valuetotext (because these are Datatypes, which otherwise might not be recognized as text).
But then I don't know how to do it. My tought was with a LOOKUP function which can find the last entry. But it is not working. I tried this: `=LOOKUP(2;1/(INDEX($AA$7#;AE7;1)<>"");INDEX($AA$7#;AE7;1))` (ranges in this formula doesn't match with the picture, just to give you an idea)

I would prefer non Lambda formulas, because I'm not familar with them. If not possible otherwise, I can use Lambda as well.

[image]

Comment: Can you try this : `=INDEX(LOOKUP(ROW($X$10:$X$35),ROW($X$10:$X$35)/($X$10:$X$35<>0),$X$10:$X$35),MATCH(U10,$V$10:$V$35,0))`

Comment: Or, you can use a `SCAN()` as well : `SCAN(X10:X35,X10:X35,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y=0,x,y))` in place of `LOOKUP()`

Comment: Rather than using a complex formula to get around incomplete data, fill in room number for every row, and use conditional formatting to create the visual effect you want (if a cell equals the row above apply format `;;;`)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Sir, absolutely agreed, there is no need for a complex formulas, fill from above is the easiest one to resolve. I personally use this feature unless there is a need for creating it.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thank you, great suggestion. I will think of it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, this is what you could have tried (I tried to recreate the data you are using except the data types):

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `U4`

```
=LET(_data,VSTACK(J4:K35,N4:O35,R4:S35),
_rooms,TAKE(_data,,1),
_combinedData,HSTACK(SCAN(_rooms,_rooms,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y=0,x,y))),TAKE(_data,,-1)),
SORT(FILTER(_combinedData,TAKE(_combinedData,,-1)<>0),,,1))
```

---

If you wish to have the header as well using the formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `U4`

```
=LET(_data,VSTACK(J4:K35,N4:O35,R4:S35),
_rooms,TAKE(_data,,1),
_combinedData,HSTACK(TAKE(_data,,-1),SCAN(_rooms,_rooms,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y=0,x,y)))),
VSTACK({"Name","Room Number"},FILTER(_combinedData,TAKE(_combinedData,,1)<>0)))
```

---

Or, If I go by the approach, you were trying then :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `X10`

```
=VSTACK(J4:K35,N4:O35,R4:S35)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `V19`

```
=IF(U19="","",INDEX(LOOKUP(ROW($X$10:$X$105),ROW($X$10:$X$105)/($X$10:$X$105<>0),$X$10:$X$105),MATCH(U19,$Y$10:$Y$105,0)))
```

---

Comment: you did so much work with it. Thank you so much! I feel a bit ashamed that I didn't provide a sample file, I had it in mind and wanted to do it a bit later... But then you had fixed everything. To me the last solution is more interesting, because I can't use a dynamic array (its in a table and need to check a specific list of names). I will try to put the vstack formula into the lookup formula, to skip helper columns.Or do you think helpercolumn is needed because of the Row()

Comment: @WeAreOne never mind and don't be ashamed about anything, we are all sharing and learning from this great community, you try your best, if you find any problem, please ask here I will try to assist again. I don't think `VSTACK()` will work with Tables, as `Structured References` do not support spill array formulas as far as i know. You try the last one. I dont think helper is required because `ROW()` function is used for that. Let me know if you face any problem

Comment: Row() is not taking any vstack() function. I tried a lot. So I can't combine these, I have to use a helper column? Maybe because row means row number in worksheet. But the vstack is kind of not in the worksheet, but it is virtual only, if you understand what I mean. I made small changes to your formula to make it "shorter" and dynamic=INDEX(LOOKUP(ROW($X$10#);ROW($X$10#)/($X$10#<>"");CHOOSECOLS($X$10#;1));MATCH(U19;CHOOSECOLS($X$10#;2);0))

Comment: @WeAreOne sorry for the delay in response. `ROW()` function will not work with `VSTACK()` as `ROW()` works with a range or cells while the latter returns an array. You could have used the `SCAN()`